# Displaying feed from ip camera using OpenCV(Emgu)

Tags: c#, video, emgucv, invoke, opencv3.0

I'm trying to create program which display video from IP Camera.

This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;                  //
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;           // usual Emgu Cv imports
using Emgu.CV.Structure;        //
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.Util;
using System.Net;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Capture _capture;
        public Mat imgOriginal;

        private void imageBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _capture = new Capture("http://192.168.1.148:8080/video");
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
            _capture.Start();
        }

        public void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            imgOriginal= _capture.QueryFrame();
            ibOriginal.Image = imgOriginal;
        }
    }
}
```

It's getting stuck on this step (without expectation):

```
imgOriginal= _capture.QueryFrame();
```

Maybe i should you invoke method but i don't know how.
Im using Emgu 3.1.0 [Link to Doc](http://file.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/18b6eba7-f18b-fa87-8bf2-2acff68988cb.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to troubleshoot this . I made some canonical and syntax mistakes. 
I provide working code for community:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;                  //
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;           // usual Emgu Cv imports
using Emgu.CV.Structure;        //
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.Util;
using System.Net;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Run();
        }

        public Capture _capture;
        public Mat imgOriginal;

        private void imageBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                _capture = new Capture("http://192.168.1.148:8080/video");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return;
            }

            Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
        }
        void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mat frame = _capture.QueryFrame();

            ibOriginal.Image = frame;
        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }


    }
}
```